# How to add CVS informations in a JSP xml format to view in the source

Tags: xml, jsp, cvs, comments

Is there a way to add CVS informations in a jsp with xml format to see thoses info in the source page?

JSP

```
<jsp:root version="2.0" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:c="urn:jsptld:http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:display="urn:jsptld:http://displaytag.sf.net"
    xmlns:lis="http://www.ep.parl.union.eu/lis/tags">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

<!-- Revision : $Id$  -->
</jsp:root>
```

But when I "view source" on a html browser, the comment doesn't appear.
By display the source, I want to know from which jsp file comes the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using the XML syntax to write your JSPs, the comment is interpreted as an XML comment, and is thus not part of the response. Try using the jsp:text directive or try with

```
&lt;!-- Revision : $Id$ --&gt;
```